# Using es6-shim in an Angular2/TypeScript project

Tags: typescript, ecmascript-6, angular, es6-shim

I want to use es6's Map for an Angular2/typescript project. I guess the way to achieve that is through the es6-shim library. However I am really confused on how I am supposed to do that. Here is what I have done so far:

On my root index.html file I have this:

```
<script src="../node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
```

The above works just fine because if I run my app now it will load with no problems.

Then, in one of my typescript files I have this:

```
import * as shim from 'es6-shim/es6-shim.js';
```

If I do this I get an error when I try to run my application:

```
GET http://localhost:63342/gbkfitcloud_client/src/es6-shim/es6-shim 404 (Not Found)
```

Isn't this strange since I included es6-shim in my index.html?

Now, if I just manually copy the es6-shim.js file in the above directory it works, I don't get any errors.

Then, I try to create a Map object like this:

```
let foo = new shim.Map();
```

But I get the following error:

```
ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: TypeError: shim.Map is not a function
```

So, since I get these strange errors I assume that I am doing something totally wrong. Can someone help me please?

Thank you!

Comment: And your environment is?.. I guess that SystemJS is used for imports, so it tries to request es6-shim package from listed url instead of bundling it locally. `import` statement has nothing to do with `<script>` tag, you probably have to figure out how `import` and SystemJS work before moving any further. And btw, it is `Map`, `shim.Map` is optional because es6-shim is a polyfill. And btw this is the reason why it shouldn't be loaded twice in the first place.

Comment: Oh God, this is embarrassing... indeed I didn't have to do anything special. No import was necessary... I don't know why it did't work the first time (and it made me to start importing stuff and so on). Thanks for the help my friend!

Comment: You're welcome. In fact, it can be imported once in entry point (bootstrap.ts or so), but since the entire application (SystemJS itself in the first place) relies on es6 features, there's no real reason to do this with import

Comment: So is it enough to include es6-shim in index.html to get it's support in the application?