# Angular 2.0 use new Promise() got error TypeError: promise_1.Promise is not a function

Tags: javascript, angular

While use new Promise in angular 2.0 got error:

> TypeError: promise_1.Promise is not a function

```
 var promise = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {

        this.buildCSV();
           .then(accesstoken => {
           this.doClick();
       })
    });
```

Comment: where do you use `promise` because you are apparently using it wrongly?

Comment: The code won't work. You need to look at this https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Comment: not exactly sure why you're getting the error you claim to get, but that is invalid js anyway ... the `.then` on line 4 should give a syntax error at least ... and nowhere in your code do you resolve or reject the created promise anyway

Comment: Don't import Promise from anywhere. Just use it, it's in the browser.

Comment: used in angular 2.0 i.e in typescript file

Comment: Promise is not an angular thing, it's a browser thing. Don't import it.

Comment: Just saying, avoid the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572).

Answer (score 1):

You should try something like that:

```
var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {          
    this.buildCSV();
});

promise.then(accesstoken => {
    this.doClick();
});
```

The then method should be used within the initialization callback of the promise.

Moreover don't forget to use arrow functions if you want to the this keyword in callbacks.

I don't see where you call the resolve / reject functions. The registered callbacks won't be called... What do you try to implement?

Regarding your error you could try to import this if the browser doesn't support promises out of the box (most of time this object is present):

```
<script src="../node_modules/es6-shim/es6-shim.js"></script>
<script src="../node_modules/es6-promise/es6-promise.js"></script>
```

In all cases, the `Promise` object can be used directly without any import... In your case the prefix promise_1 is à bit strange and names me think that you try to import it from something.

See this question for more details:

- [Using es6-shim in an Angular2/TypeScript project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34488074/using-es6-shim-in-an-angular2-typescript-project)

Comment: the `.then` callback would never be called, because `resolve`  or `reject` is never called. And if `this.buildCSV()` returns a promise then the `new Promise`  is not required at all.

Comment: I had already use that one but still got error                                      TypeError: promise_1.Promise is not a function

Comment: Yes agreed! It's not clear to me what is the use case ;-) See the last part ofy answer...

Comment: Perhaps your browser doesn't support es6 promise out of the box. Did you try to include the es6-promise.js file?

Comment: buildCSV() it contain api call so promise is wait until it getting the result and after successful getting result doClick() is executed.

Comment: How do you know that processing in the buildCsv method ends? Is it asynchronous processing?